# Trying to add a custom application to Gnosis Safe App

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to add my react application as a custom application via Gnosis Safe App and I'm facing Cors Error when trying to access manifest.json.
I did everything according to the instructions, manifest.json is in the public folder, gives 200 status code, but CORS.
I use craco instead of react rewired.

module.exports = {
devServer: function (configFunction) {
return function (proxy, allowedHost) {
const config = configFunction(proxy, allowedHost);

```
  config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET';
  config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization';

  return config;
};
```

},
};

This is what craco config looks like , when trying to add localhost:3000 , The app doesn't support Safe App functionality

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the files in your directory are normal，add on server：

```
  location / {
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';

      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
              # return 204;
      }

  }
```